# I got an RuntimeError when making an discord AI chat bot, "RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, discord.py

I was trying to make a discord AI chatbot, it had worked before when I ran it again, it had the RuntimeError. I do not understand what it means? It has worked when I use it to perform in the terminal, but when put into discord format is creates this error, so the issue may be in the discord code section(below). But it has worked using discord.py as well, just for some reason doesn't work anymore?

````
nltk.download('punkt')

from nltk import word_tokenize,sent_tokenize

from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import numpy as np 
import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import json
import pickle
import discord

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

try:
    with open("data.pickle","rb") as f:
        words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)

except:
    words = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []
    for intent in data["intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(wrds)
            docs_x.append(wrds)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])
            
        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])


    words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))
    labels = sorted(labels)

    training = []
    output = []
    out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

    for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
        bag = []

        wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in doc]

        for w in words:
            if w in wrds:
               bag.append(1)
            else:
              bag.append(0)
    
        output_row = out_empty[:]
        output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1
        
        training.append(bag)
        output.append(output_row)

    training = np.array(training)
    output = np.array(output)
    
    with open("data.pickle","wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)



net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")


def bag_of_words(s, words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]

    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

    for se in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == se:
                bag[i] = 1
    
    return np.array(bag)



class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('Bot is Online')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return
       
        else:
           inp = message.content
           result = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])[0]
           result_index = np.argmax(result)
           tag = labels[result_index]
        for tg in data["intents"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
                responses = tg['responses']
                
        bot_response=random.choice(responses)
        await message.channel.send(bot_response.format(message))

              
client = MyClient()
client.run(TOKEN)```

***This was the error:***

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mwkje_h8e091g/OneDrive/Documents/VSCODEPROD/DiscordAI ver.last/main.py", line 86, in <module>
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
  File "C:\Users\mwkje_h8e091g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 206, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\mwkje_h8e091g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 344, in fit
    show_metric)
  File "C:\Users\mwkje_h8e091g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 826, in _train
    tflearn.is_training(True, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\mwkje_h8e091g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 95, in is_training
    tf.get_collection('is_training_ops')[0].eval(session=session)
  File "C:\Users\mwkje_h8e091g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 913, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "C:\Users\mwkje_h8e091g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5512, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "C:\Users\mwkje_h8e091g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 958, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\mwkje_h8e091g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1104, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.```
````